# Read a wsdl file and get tags referring to a particular namespace in java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

I have a huge WSDL file,I need to parse it and check if its a valid WSDL.
 I found that we can validate XML against XSD using Validator Object as follows:

```
javax.xml.validation.Schema schema2 = factory.newSchema(new File("D:\\Test3\\Admin.xsd"));
             Validator validator = ((javax.xml.validation.Schema) schema2).newValidator();
             validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File("abc.xml")));
```

But since we need to do the same for WSDL, I was thinking maybe I could find all the tags in the WSDL which refer to a particular Namespace(hence Schema) and write them to a xml file. Then use Validator object.

Issue is, how should I extract the elements/tags that refer to a particular XSD form the WSDL?
Or if there is a wiser/simpler solution Please Help
Thanks

Comment: Why not just validate your WSDL against [the existing WSDL schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#A4.1)?

Comment: Because we have external user defined schemas imported in the wsdl, we need to validate against them.